# Historical data on valuations for internet companies during dot-com bubble

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, pricing, valuation

I am looking for data on historical valuations for internet companies during the years of the dot-com bubble (2000 - 2002). I know that big auditors have or at least have access to such data on historical valuations for different categories of companies in different countries. I am not only looking for market-data but also for the bigger picture of prices of acquisitions or even testified value assessments.

My question is: where can I find such data (commercially or open-access)?